# Obtendo a hora digitada em javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Pessoa, tenho uma simples form onde o usuário deve digitar a hora.

```
<form name="formAgendamento" class="formAgendamento">
    <label>Dia</label>
    <input class="form-control dia" type="date" name="dia" ng-model="agendamento.dia" required>
    <label>Hora</label>
    <input class="form-control hora" type="time" name="hora" ng-model="agendamento.hora" required>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="formAgendamento.$invalid" ng-click="agendar(agendamento)">Agendar</button>
</form>
```

Porém a hora vai no seguinte formato para o angular:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso, apenas das horas e minutos (17:17)... Como faço pra pegar apenas esses dados?
Estou tentando usar o "split()" do javascript, mas no console aparece um aviso dizendo que split não é uma função.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19346876/4551469 vê se ajuda esse link

Comment: Acho que sim @rLinhares

Comment: Aqui sem usar o split, mais simples:

`var horaMinuto = new Date().toString().match(/\d{2}\:\d{2}/)[0];`

Comment: Não entendi como o moment.js pega a data informada pelo usuário... Pelo que vi da documentação ele pega os dados do sistema.

Answer (score 0):

## Erro no split()

A questão aqui é que o split() precisa ser utilizado em um string e você esta tentando utilizado em um objeto.

```
    var hora = new Date(); // Thu Aug 10 2017 21:19:18 GMT-0300 (BRT)
    typeof data;           // object
```

Se você fizer

```
    data.split(" ");       // Terá o erro 'data.split is not a function'
```

### Resolvendo

Então você precisa pegar a data como uma string e depois utilizar o split. Pode ser feito assim:

```
    var data = new Date().toString();
    typeof data;          // Você verá "string"
    var dataSeparada = data.split(" ");
    dataSeparada[4];      // "21:21:55"
    var horaMinuto = dataSeparada[4].substring(0,5)
    horaMinuto;           // "21:21"
```

## Update

Em seu vetor, para pegar o dia use:

```
    dia.toString().match(/\d{2}/)[0]
```

E para hora:

```
    hora.toString().match(/\d{2}:\d{2}/)[0]
```

Regex como feita pelo Leandro Simões vai ajudar muito.

Comment: Mas dessa forma estou pegando a data e hora do sistema, porém preciso pegar os dados que o usuário informou, entende?

Comment: Verifique o update.

Comment: Ahhhh agora entendi. Valeu.